# CentOS 7 unable to connect clamd.sock file (Permission denied error)

Tags: php, sockets, centos7, clam

I am trying to scan uploaded files on PHP server using clamAV. I've installed ClamAV on my server (Centos 7). Currently, I am using PHP 7, so I am using Clamd socket connection to scan uploaded files. I've enabled PHP sockets, clamd.sock file is present at `/var/run/clamd.scan/` folder with apache owner.

My Socket connection code -

```
        $socket = socket_create(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

        if(socket_connect($socket, '/var/run/clamd.scan/clamd.sock')) {
            return $socket;
        }
```

When I try to run above code on the browser I am getting error as `socket_connect(): unable to connect [13]: Permission denied`, But if I run the PHP code through command line with a user as root it is working fine.

I know there is some issue with SELinux policy with Centos as if I disable SELinux policy everything is working fine from the browser as well. I have checked `httpd_can_network_connect --> on` and `antivirus_can_scan_system --> on` both are on.

The issue is with accessing anything inside `/var/run/` folder for `apache` user, there is something (some policy) from SELinux which is stopping apache to connect to clamd socket file. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging, got to know that this is SELinux policy issue.
You need to enable daemons_enable_cluster_mode policy in SELinux.

To Enable daemons_enable_cluster_mode:

```
setsebool -P daemons_enable_cluster_mode 1
```

This will allow executing ClamAV scan through another service like Apache in my case.

Comment: I had try this , but it still occur Permission denied error. can you share all your step install?